# Create intervals in R

Tags: r, loops, intervals

I want to create intervals in R, I already got some code to get specific numbers.

For example the following:

```
"33" "45" "77" "82" "85"
```

As the result I want to get the following, the most important is to get the ranges, it doesnt have to look like this exactly:

```
c(0,33), c(34,45), c(46,77), c(78,82), c(83,85), c(86,100)
```

How can I achieve this for any given example of numbers? 0 should always be the minimum and 100 always the max.

I have tried something like this, but obviously this can't work because k is not defined:

```
for(number in numbers) {
    interval = c(number[k] +1, number[k+1])
```

Comment: Something like: `cbind(x - 1, x + 1)`

Answer (score 2):

In a matrix

```
x=c(33,45,77,82,85)
cbind(
  c(0,x+1),
  c(x,100)
)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   33
[2,]   34   45
[3,]   46   77
[4,]   78   82
[5,]   83   85
[6,]   86  100
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast solution, it worked as I wanted, I will accept your answer in a few minutes. Its not possible yet.